# Unexpected compilation problem with g++ -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some compilation problems pushing back elements of type T to a vector when compiling with g++ -std=c++0x.

This is a minimal example:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { }

    A& operator=(A &orig) {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A a;
    vector<A> b;
    A c = a; // This is fine
    b.push_back(a); // This is not, but only when compiling with -std=c++0x!
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine with g++ -Wall -pedantic, but it gives this error when compiling with g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x:

```
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/vector:69,
                 from min.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = const A&, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:741:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]’
min.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:314: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘__position.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = A*, _Container = std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> >]() = ((const A&)((const A*)std::forward [with _Tp = const A&](((const A&)((const A*)__args#0)))))’
min.cpp:11: note: candidates are: A& A::operator=(A&)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/vector:61,
                 from min.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function ‘static _BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = A*, _BI2 = A*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:595:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = A*, _BI2 = A*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:605:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = A*, _BI2 = A*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:676:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = A*, _BI2 = A*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:308:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = const A&, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:741:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]’
min.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:561: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘* -- __result = std::move [with _Tp = A&](((A&)(-- __last)))’
min.cpp:11: note: candidates are: A& A::operator=(A&)
```

So it seems that it doesn't find the right operator= of A. Why? Why it states `with _Iterator = A*` when I'm passing A?

Comment: It works if your assignment operator takes a `const`-reference, which it always should.

Comment: It also works if I declare it as A& operator=(A *orig), but why? And why it works anyway with "plain" g++?

Comment: `A& operator=(A *orig)` is an assignment operator, but not a _copy-assignment_ operator, so the compiler implicitly defines the default copy-assignment operator for you (the same as though you had defined no assignment operator at all).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *Assignable* requirement imposted by the language standard on the standard container elements requires the `t = u` expression to be valid even if `u` is a const object. The requirement was defined that way since C++98 (see 23.1/4)

You violated that requirement, since your assignment operator does not accept const objects. This immediately mean that your class `A` cannot be used as a container element type.

Why it worked in C++03 is rather irrelevant. It worked by accident. It is obvious from the error message that the C++0x implementation of the library uses some C++0x specific features (like `std::move`), which is what makes the above requirement to come into play. But anyway, a C++03 implementation (and even C++98 implementation) can also fail to compile for your `A`.

Your example with `A c = a;` is irrelevant, since it does not use the assignment operator at all (why is it here?).

In order to fix the error you should either accept the parameter by const reference or by value.

Comment: Thanks. Assignable requirement is defined only in C++0x, or it is just enforced in g++ when compiled with -std=c++0x?

Comment: @akappa: The *Assignable* requirement was there since C++98. So, you code is generally non-compilable in any version of standard C++. It just that in GCC implementation of pre-C++0x standard you got lucky and the error slipped through. But in C++0x it is no longer the case.

Comment: @AndreyT: I though that A c = a does the following things: (1) Instantiates c using the "empty" constructor (2) uses the assignment operator upon c to "make it equal" to a. I'm rather a novice, so my understanding of the language is flawed :) Would you be so nice to explain me what's going in A c = a?

Comment: @akappa : `A c = a;` doesn't use assignment at all, and is consequently irrelevant here (it's using copy construction). `A c; c = a;` is what's being discussed. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: so C++ is implicitly defining a copy constructor? Because I've not defined one...

Comment: @akappa : Correct; just as a copy-assignment operator is implicitly defined for you whenever possible, a copy-constructor is also implicitly defined for you whenever possible. (Same goes for a default constructor and a destructor.)

Comment: I believe that he can also work with *Move* Assignable types. But this requires a move assignment operator in addition, which he doesn't have either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure this is a safety feature. Types with a copy-assignment operator (or a copy constructor) that may mutate the right-hand side are *not* safe to use in standard containers - an example of this is (the now deprecated) `std::auto_ptr` which will break horribly if stored in a container.

The old C++03 library implementation permitted such unsafe code, but apparently they implemented a compile-time check in the C++0x version -- probably in conjunction with move-enabling the containers.

Comment: This would completely answer my question, although the error message chosen would be *terrible* :)

Answer (score 1):

The standard's definition of copy-assignment operator is (section `[class.copy]`):

> A user-declared *copy* assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

But the `X&` and `volatile X&` variants may not be compatible with containers assuming an assignment can be made from an r-value RHS.

NOTE: Passing by value, e.g. `X::operator=(X)` is a fundamental part of the copy-and-swap idiom.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. So, in the end, you agree with JohannesD about why it fails in C++03 and not in C++0x?