# C++11 copy assignment for std::complex in g++ 4.5 - no match for 'operator+'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++11, complextype

The code below fails to compile with g++ version 4.5.0 using the `-std=c++0x` switch. I get the following error message:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' in 'std::pow [with _Tp = float, _Up = int, typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type = double](((const std::complex<float>&)((const std::complex<float>*)(& x))), ((const int&)((const int*)(&2)))) + y'
```

I believe this relates to the *Assignable* requirement mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090306/unexpected-compilation-problem-with-g-std-c0x). Should I define my own copy assignment operator for complex? If so, how?

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  complex<float> x,y;
  x = pow(x,2);      // ok
  x = x        + y;  // ok
  x = pow(x,2) + y;  // error
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error, simplified, says "There is no operator+ that takes a complex<double> and a complex<float>"

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: This compiles on VS2010 perhaps need template or typename keyword.

Comment: Does changing 2 to 2.0f help ?

Comment: It works if you use `2.0f`, or if you use `complex<double>`. I'm not sure where gcc gets `double` from here, may be a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[cmplx.over]/p3 specifies additional overloads for `pow` when `complex` is involved:

> Function template pow shall have additional overloads sufficient to
>   ensure, for a call with at least one argument of type `complex<T>`:
>
> 1. If either argument has type `complex<long double>` or type `long double`, then both arguments are effectively cast to `complex<long
>      double>`.
> 2. Otherwise, if either argument has type `complex<double>`, `double`, or an integer type, then both arguments are effectively cast to
>      `complex<double>`.
> 3. Otherwise, if either argument has type `complex<float>` or `float`, then both arguments are effectively cast to `complex<float>`.

The 2 is being promoted to a double, and `pow(complex<float>, double)` returns a `complex<double>`.

Comment: Additional detail: The difference from C++03 can be traced back to this defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#844  - they removed an additional overload: template<class T> complex<T> pow(const complex<T>& x, int y);

Comment: I see, thanks. In C++03 the same `pow(x,2)` returned a `complex<float>` instead of `complex<double>`; and there never has been an `operator+` between `complex<float>` and `complex<double>`.